# Window 2097163 has no colormap

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting started with OPENFOAM in WSL2, and when I try to run the pitzDailySteady tutorial I get this error message.

```
QStandardPaths: wrong permissions on runtime directory /run/user/1000/, 0755 instead of 0700
Mesa warning: Window 2097160 has no colormap!
Mesa warning: Window 2097163 has no colormap!
```

I have tried to solve it by running `paraFoam -builtin`, but it does not work

Comment: Those are just warnings.  Does the program actually work?  If so, try launching it with a `2>/dev/null` after it so that you don't see those warnings.  And yes, the `/run/user/1000` should be permissions 0700.  `chmod 700 /run/user/1000`